# Loading '*.mat' correctly but form another unknown location

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler, matlab-load

I got 2 functions in my matlab script. These functions exchange the data via a `*.mat` file.
In one of the functions, I read the number of specific files and a data from them. Later I process and store the variable `ggd` in `proj1.mat` file. As shown below :

```
    function browse_pushBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to browse_pushBtn (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.directory = uigetdir('C:\temp\');
guidata(hObject,handles);
ggd.directory = handles.directory;
if (ggd.directory)
    set(handles.browse_textEdit,'String',handles.directory);
    disp2listbox(handles.mainLog_listBox, '1. Searching for GGD Datafile:');
    ggd = MyRead(ggd);
    disp2listbox(handles.mainLog_listBox, sprintf('     -%d Bilder 
    gefunden',length(ggd.bilds)));
    save proj1 ggd;
else
    set(handles.browse_textEdit,'String','Select a directory');
end
```

The Second function is :

```
function start_pushBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to start_pushBtn (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

option = get(handles.mainMenu,'Value');
if (option == 1)
    disp2listbox(handles.mainLog_listBox, '2. Calculating the quadratic size..');
    fprintf('path is : %s\n', pwd); % did just to check the path (for debugging purpose)
    load proj1 ggd;
    ggd = MyProcess(ggd); 
    save proj1 ggd;
    disp2listbox(handles.mainLog_listBox, sprintf('     -MySize: %d X %d',ggd.X(1), ggd.Y(2)));
    disp2listbox(handles.mainLog_listBox, '3. opening another function...');
    % call to another function 
elseif (option == 2)
    disp2listbox(handles.mainLog_listBox, '2. opening third function...');
    % call to third different function
end
```

The funny thing is that these two functions work perfectly fine when I run them in Matlab tool.
Later, I compile the standalone executable for my application. This standalone application works fine until the first function; but, when I call the second function, it loads the `proj1.mat` file from another unknown location that contains totally different data.
Have no idea what is the problem that causing such weird behaviour.

I checked the current paths (`pwd`) in second function while executing standalone 
 and found it to be the same as the one in first function.

Any ideas ??

Comment: It is possible the second function included an existing mat file when you compiled it. Try deleting that file when you are compiling.

Comment: You might find [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/11/path-management-in-deployed-applications/) useful

Comment: @Navan I also thought of the same possibiliy but can you please guide me how can I delete **'that *.mat '** while compiling - thanks

Comment: You cannot do it while compiling. You need to do that before compiling.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep writing and reading from a file in a deployed application, I would recommend creating a local directory in user's machine's App Data and storing all the files there. You can do this by using the [following](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15886-get-application-data-directory?focused=5091699&tab=function) function from matlab central. E.g. something like

```
file_root = getapplicationdatadir('your.application.name',1,1);
```

should create a directory (if it does not exist) on the user's computer where it will store all the files, and variable `root` will give you the absolute path to that directory. You can then use it to save and load the files. E.g.

```
save([file_root '/proj1.mat'],'ggd');
```

in the first function, and

```
load([file_root '/proj1.mat'],'ggd');
```

in the second function. This way you know exactly where the file is stored. Also, read the [link](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/11/path-management-in-deployed-applications/) I mentioned earlier in the comment.

Comment: thanks I tried this already.. but was still curious to know the reason.. thank you again